# Can all unprovable statements in a given mathematical theory be determined with the addition of a finite number of new axioms?

Tags: logic, foundations, incompleteness

This question is related to Godel's incompleteness theorem, which states that no sufficiently complex formal system can be both consistent and complete.

Is it possible to add axioms to a formal system $P$ to generate a new formal system $P'$ such that $P'$ is consistent and all unprovable statements in $P$ have proof in $P'$? (The way that this would circumvent Godel's incompleteness theorem is that there would be new unprovable statements in $P'$ that weren't in $P$).

For example, primitive recursive arithmetic is a formal system in which everything is provable, however it can only express a subset of the theories that can be expressed by Peano arithmatic. In the same way, $P'$ would be more expressive than $P$, and primitive recursive arithmatic represents a trivial case of $P$ where the above question is true. I am interested in $P$ where there exist unprovable statements.

Comment: For the parenthesis at the end: How could the addition of new axioms possibly make something unprovable that wasn't already?

Comment: $P'$ would be more expressive than $P$ in the same way that Peano arithmetic is more expressive than primitive recursive arithmetic.

Comment: How will you stop $P'$ from being able to solve the halting problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding more expressivity is not going to help you if Gödel's incompleteness theorem applies to $P$.

One of the premises of Gödel's theorem is that the language of the theory can express a certain amount of arithmetic sentences (level $\Pi^0_1$ in the arithmetical hierarchy, if I recall correctly).

If we add more expressivity to $P$, producing $P'$ with a *finite* number of consistent additional axioms, then Gödel's theorem still applies to $P'$. But the $P'$-undecidable sentence that the theorem produces will be one of the arithmetic sentences that already $P$ could express.

So $P'$ *will* have an undecidable sentence that was in the language of $P$.

Comment: What if $P'$ also extends the language of $P$ with new relation or function symbols?  (For example, maybe $P'$ adds a function symbol which represents an oracle on "$n$ is an encoding of a true statement" and then you add axioms that the oracle gives consistent answers.  Though I haven't thought that through and there could very well be subtle issues with trying to do that.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler: Extending the language is exactly what I'm showing _doesn't_ help. (Note that the question title stipulated a _finite_ number of new axioms; I dare you to attempt to specify a truth oracle for arithmetic within that constraint).